# How to detect if the user has linked to Google Market account

Tags: android, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find Gmail account associated with Android Market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606976/how-to-find-gmail-account-associated-with-android-market)

In Android, is there an easy way in code to detect if the user has linked their phone to Google Market using a gmail address?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like the right thing to ask at this point is, "What are you really trying to do?"

The most obvious use case I can think of is to verify that the user is legitimately using your app, in which case you might find the right answer in Application Licensing: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/index.html

The next most obvious use case I can think of is you want to help the user install something, in which case maybe your answer is in Linking to your Application: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

For other cases, the answer may begin with Account Manager.  Try here: http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html

Comment: Wow thanks. I did not know that there was something like that !

Comment: Thanks Sparky. What I am trying to achieve here is to warn user that their push notification (c2dm) won't work if the phone is not linked to any Google market account.

Comment: Hi Michael, got it.  In that case, I think the AccountManager route is what you want.  Alternatively, since the app requires a (Market) Play account anyway, you could distribute it only through that channel. ;-)  You could also put your disclaimer in the copy in your download listing.  Or try to register as a C2DM receiver and see if it fails.  And if you can't get C2DM (GCM) on a device, well, there's always polling as a fallback position.