# Link Google Play In App Purchase to a specific UserId

Tags: in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase, google-play-billing

Forgive me if this is answered, somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Similiar issues that don't solve my problem:
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863113/android-get-google-play-account-associated-with-in-app-billing) - This won't work for me because Google Play allow users to unsubscribe from the application from outside of the app, so I will not have a way of knowing

I have an application that allows users to link their bank accounts to their app accounts. Users can subscribe to different tiers that allow them to link a certain number of accounts (tier 1 = 1 link, tier 2 = 2 links, etc.). I also have a feature that allows users to share their database with other users, so they can link more accounts together.(ex: user 1 could have subscription tier 1, and user 2 could have subscription tier 2 and they together could link 3 accounts from one database).

However, I am facing an issue where a user can buy a subscription for a lower tier, link an account, and then sign in with a different email on the same device and use the "restore purchases" feature to link more accounts without paying for a higher subscription tier. I need a way to identify each Google Play billing user uniquely so that I can link their billing user to one user account. This will ensure that the "restore purchases" feature only works if the user is signed in with the correct account.

Can you please suggest a solution or workaround for my issue?